# Insert DIV inside php code

Tags: php, html

I have modified my opensource Shopping cart in Joomla, but I am not able to insert a DIV for 2 pieces of information.

My cart looks like this in frontend :

---

DIN INDKØBSKURV

**1 x SALE rund gul hvid** (quantity x Product name)

**Pris 10,00**  (Product price)

Ialt ex moms DKK:10,00 (Total price)

---

I need to add divs on

> "1 x SALE rund gul hvid" = div class="mod_cart_product_name" id="mod_cart_product_name"

AND

> "Pris 10,00" = div class="mod_cart_productprice" id="mod_cart_productprice"

I can´t do it my self because of the ELSE and IF codes :-)

I have extracted the code for the like this:

```
case 'extended':

    $output = '<div class="mod_cart_products" id="mod_cart_products">';
    if ($count)
    {
        $cartTotalProduct = $idx;

        for($i = 0; $i < $idx; $i ++)
        {
            $carthelper         = new rsCarthelper();
            if($carthelper->rs_multi_array_key_exists('giftcard_id',$cart [$i]) && $cart [$i] ['giftcard_id'])
            {
                $giftcardData = $producthelper->getGiftcardData($cart [$i] ['giftcard_id']);
                $name = $giftcardData->giftcard_name;
            }
            else
            {
                $product_detail = $producthelper->getProductById ( $cart [$i] ['product_id'] );
                $name = $product_detail->product_name;
            }
            $output .= $cart [$i] ['quantity'] . " x " . $name . "<br />";
            if (! DEFAULT_QUOTATION_MODE || (DEFAULT_QUOTATION_MODE && SHOW_QUOTATION_PRICE))
            {
                if ($show_with_vat)
                {
                    $output .= JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_PRICE' ) . " " . $producthelper->getProductFormattedPrice ( $cart [$i] ['product_price'], true ) . "<br />";
                }
                else
                {
                    $output .= JText::_('COM_REDSHOP_PRICE' ) . " " . $producthelper->getProductFormattedPrice ( $cart [$i] ['product_price_excl_vat'], true ) . "<br />";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $output .='</div>';
```

Comment: What do you mean `I can´t do it my self because of the ELSE and IF codes`? What happens if you add `$output.="<div class=...>"` within each block appropriately?

Comment: I mean i don´t know where to put it in each block. I break the code when i try. I am not very good with php coding :-)